# HTML5 File Reader & jQuery: How to log a file's contents to the console

Tags: jquery, html, filereader

I'm trying to read a text file and print its contents to the console using jquery and the HTML5 file reader. (will try to phrase it later but that's going to be another problem) to load some UI presets. But cant figure out HTML5 reader for the life of me.

Can someone tell me whats the problem with this code?

```
$('#fileInput').change(function() {

var file = fileInput;
var reader = new FileReader();

reader.onload = function(e) {
fileContent = reader.result;
}

reader.readAsText(file);    

console.log(fileContent);
 });
```

https://jsfiddle.net/xLtgcg4m/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- `console.log(fileContent);` should be inside the `onload`
- And get the `files[0]`*th* file from `file` Object using `file.files[0]`

```js
$('#fileInput').change(function() {

  var file = fileInput;
  var reader = new FileReader();

  reader.onload = function(e) {
    fileContent = reader.result;
    console.log(fileContent);     
  }
  reader.readAsText(file.files[0]);    

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="file" id="fileInput" title="Load File" />
```

`files[0]` `0` for the simplest reason you're not iterating over a *file* input with type `multiple`. If you used `multiple` than you would iterate over all `files[n]`

Comment: Thank you! I still dont really understand this line tho: reader.readAsText(file.files[0]);

Comment: @user2999177 `file` are actually file**s**!! Object. It provies further a  `files` Object Array. You need to get the `[0]` file. If you used `<input type="file" multiple>` than the `files` array would have all the files the user selected.

Comment: Here's a link to the documentation https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FileReader/readAsText